# How to use ngswitch with enum in template?

Tags: angular, enums, ng-switch

I'm trying to change template with enum values.
TS:

```
enum NumType {
  first, second, third
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
      <div [ngSwitch]="numType">
        <a *ngSwitchCase="numType.first" href="first">first</a>
        <a *ngSwitchCase="numType.second" href="second">second</a>
        <a *ngSwitchCase="numType.third" href="third">third</a>
      </div>
  `,
})
export class TestElementComponent {
  @Input() readonly numType: NumType;
}
```

HTML:

```
<app-test
[numType]="numType.first"
></app-info-element>
```

And then I've got this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
```

Can you please tell me what needs to be done to make it work?
Angular 8 used.

Answer (score 2):

in .html only can use variables that **belong** to the component. So, if you use a enum you should use a variable in your component. It's the reason generally you use a .ts with definitions

```
//definitions.ts
export enum NumType { //<---see the word "export"
  first, second, third
}
```

Your main component

```
   import {NumType} from './definitions'
   numType=NumType

   //now you can use
   <app-test [type]="numType.first"></app-test>
```

Your app-test sould import also the "NumType"

```
   import {NumType} from './definitions'

   numType=NumType
   @Input() type:NumType  //<--the input has no possible called "numType"

   //now you can use -see that the "switch" is about "type"
   <div [ngSwitch]="type">
        <a *ngSwitchCase="numType.first" href="first">first</a>
        <a *ngSwitchCase="numType.second" href="second">second</a>
        <a *ngSwitchCase="numType.third" href="third">third</a>
   </div>
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dsn6vh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

BTW, you're using `<a href>`, if you want to work with angular you should use

```
 <a routerLink="....">
```

see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)