# Use custom enum in angular template component parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have a component that has a click handler which takes in an enum type as a parameter and would like to use that enum type in the component html template when the handler is called, however I get a type error:

`Argument of type '"ERROR"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DownloadType'`

enum

```
export enum DownloadType {
  CURRENT = "CURRENT",
  ALL = "ALL",
  ERROR = "ERROR",
}
```

action-bar.component.ts

```
onDownload(downloadType: DownloadType) {
  // do stuff
}
```

action-bar.component.html

```
<button (click)="onDownload('ERROR')">Download Errors</button>
```

I have tried supplying the enum value without quotes to the handler as well, but that also did not work (`"onDownload(DownloadType.ERROR)"`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101920/how-to-use-ngswitch-with-enum-in-template/68102313#68102313 (declare a variable in your .ts: `DownloadType=DownloadType` to use in your .html `onDownload(DownloadType.ERROR)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Eliseo 's comment, just adding a field to the component that is equal to the enum type works

```
import { DownloadType } from "/path/enums.ts"

@Component({
  templateUrl: "./action-bar.component.html",
})
export class ActionBarComponent {
  // stuff
  DownloadType = DownloadType
  // other component stuff
}
```

And then just use the enum in the html file as you would use any other enum.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the enum you could simly create a type like this:

```
export type DownloadType = "CURRENT" | "ALL" | "ERROR";
```